# Pulling limbs in box2d

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I am using Box2d (libgdx) to implement a BMX bike with its rider. The bike is one body and each limb of the rider is one body. When airborne during a jump, the player should be able to control not the rider but the bike. Since the rider is connected to bike at the handlebar and at the pedals, the limbs will follow the bike, until the arms/legs are fully stretched at which point the movement of the bike is restricted.

Can anyone suggest a good way of using joints (probably) to achieve this? Both the bike and the rider should be affected by gravity, but the rider body should not collapse due to gravity. It's OK to have the limbs stiff and unaffected by gravity (their internal positions, that is), but the limbs must be affected by the bike. Preferably the internal positions of the rider limbs should be affected for example when the bikes does a heavy landing against the ground, but this is second priority.

I could set angle limits on the limb joints to prevent it from collapsing, but then I guess they will not budge when I try to move the bike.

Answer (score 0):

If the limbs follow the bike, how can the arms/legs get fully stretched?

I think first you'll need to set limits for the limb joints to stop them from turning inside-out in violent collisions (eg. elbow joint turns backwards).

Then you could determine a target angle for each joint in the resting position, and each time step, use the joint motor to make the joint move to the rest position. If you make these joint motors just strong enough to hold the rider upright, but not too much stronger, then he should be affected by a heavy landing.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't being exact enough. The whole limbs don't follow the bike. Only the hands and feet follow the exact movement of the handle bar pedal. In real life, the rider would stretch arms/legs to move the bike relative to his body. In the game I would prefer the other way around (bike moves, arms/legs stretches) for practical game control reasons.

Comment: Regarding your motor suggestion, just to be clear, I guess you mean that the motors should be used for stability only, not to achieve the goal that the hands/feet should follow the bike. What do you mean with the "resting position"? Like a stored previous joint angle that we want to preserve  by cancelling out the effects of the rider collapsing from his own weight? Sounds promising, but how would I prevent this cancelling effect from cancelling out the forces from the bike pulling at the hands/feet?

Comment: Exactly, a stored previous joint angle, for example the ideal/natural/resting angle between upper and lower arm might be say 140deg. As the rider gets bumped around the angle between the limb segments might become 120deg, so the motor speed should be made positive, etc. You can see an example of this here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbUBAr7S_Wk (in the video I'm simply switching between multiple stored joint angle configurations) To make sure the bike pulls the player into position instead of vice-versa, you'll need to make the bike significantly heavier than the rider.